# Intent.ACTION_VIEW doesn't work in searchable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-search

I'm trying to set Intent.ACTION_VIEW while the user clicks the search-suggestion. It still does the ACTION_SEARCH intent so it searches for the provided info in the suggestion-box, but I want it to pass it to Activity which already shows the clicked object. I don't use SearchActivity with its methods (onNewIntent etc.), I use only Activity, which shows list of result - its set as _default_searchable.

But what should I do if i need to pass it to different activity, when the suggestion item is selected?

I've set `android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"` and intent-filter in  the second activity in Manifest to intent.VIEW but it doesnt work

Do you have any idea, how to do that?

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.animalist.SuggestionProvider" 
        android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
        android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"


         />
```

Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <provider
                    android:authorities="com.example.animalist.SuggestionProvider"
                    android:name=".SuggestionProvider" >
                </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".SearchActivity"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.MoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_more"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.animalist.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.animalist.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.animalist.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.animalist.MainActivity" />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </activity>

    </application>
```

Provider

```
public class SuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "SuggestionProvider";

    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher sURLMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] {
            "_id",
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA
    };

    public SuggestionProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                String query = url.getLastPathSegment();
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);

                ParseQuery<Animal> squery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
            try {

                List<Animal> results = squery.find();
                for (Animal animal : results) {
                        addRow(cursor,  animal.getAnimal());
            } }catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return cursor;}
        return null;
                }





    private void addRow(MatrixCursor cursor, String string) {
        long id = cursor.getCount();
        cursor .newRow().add(id).add(string).add(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH).add(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri url) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL: " + url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri url, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("update not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("insert not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("delete not supported");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it isn't exactly a nice way of doing if, I have solved this before by making a transparent activity which handles both intents for VIEW and SEARCH.

From this activity you can launch the activities which are going to handle either case and finish the transparent activity, passing in the search parameters.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. So this activity isnt visible, it only handles the intents?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find a way to have the search suggestion point to an activity for each intent. The other option would be to have an activity which loads a different fragment for VIEW and SEARCH, so you don't need to create the transparent activity.